# Multi-level grouping nodes with xslt : how to hide parent node in output?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>

<PLANTS>
    <PLANT>
        <NAME>APPLE</NAME>
        <SIZE>SMALL</SIZE>
        <TYPE>FRUIT</TYPE>
    </PLANT>
    <PLANT>
        <NAME>CUCUMBER</NAME>
        <SIZE>SMALL</SIZE>
        <TYPE>VEGETABLE</TYPE>
    </PLANT>
    <PLANT>
        <NAME>WATERMELON</NAME>
        <SIZE>BIG</SIZE>
        <TYPE>FRUIT</TYPE>
    </PLANT>
     <PLANT>
        <NAME>ORANGE</NAME>
        <SIZE>SMALL</SIZE>
        <TYPE>FRUIT</TYPE>
    </PLANT>
    <PLANT>
        <NAME>CARROT</NAME>
        <SIZE>SMALL</SIZE>
        <TYPE>VEGETABLE</TYPE>
    </PLANT>
</PLANTS>
```

I want to represent this data as HTML table, grouping by Type, then by Size.
So far I have this XSLT code (it's necessary for me to use xslt-1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cfg="http://tempuri.org/config" exclude-result-prefixes="cfg">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="Type" match="PLANT" use="TYPE"/>
   <xsl:key name="TypeSize" match="PLANT" use="concat(TYPE, '|', SIZE)"/>

   <xsl:template match="PLANTS">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="type" select="PLANT[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Type', TYPE)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="TYPE" />
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="PLANT" mode="type">

      <xsl:variable name="type" select="TYPE"/>
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td >TYPE :
                  <xsl:value-of select="$type"/></td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="typeSize" select="key('Type', $type)[generate-id()  = generate-id(key('TypeSize',concat(TYPE, '|', SIZE))[1])]"/>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>


   <xsl:template match="PLANT" mode="typeSize">
      <xsl:variable name="typeSize" select="concat(TYPE, '|', SIZE)"/>
      <tr>
         <td >SIZE :
            <xsl:value-of select="SIZE"/></td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('TypeSize',$typeSize)">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
            </td>

         </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="PLANT">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the output is:

```
<PLANTS>
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>TYPE :
               FRUIT
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>SIZE :
               SMALL
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>APPLE</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>ORANGE</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>SIZE :
               BIG
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>WATERMELON</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>TYPE :
               VEGETABLE
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>SIZE :
               SMALL
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>CUCUMBER</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>CARROT</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</PLANTS>
```

The output is almost perfect, but I want to get rid out this `<PLANTS>` tag. How can I do it?

You can find all the code [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mK/2)

Answer (score 1):

You create it in

```
<xsl:template match="PLANTS">
  <xsl:copy>
```

so simply remove that `xsl:copy` and just apply your templates (or set up some HTML document structure, given that you say you want HTML output).

Comment: In addition, I don't think you need the last template.

Comment: thanks! It's so obvious, i don't uderstand why did I overlooked that